# How to remove rows based on combined duplicated values in other rows?

Tags: pandas, group-by, row

Given a dataset of 8 columns, I would like to check if there is a row that match specific values based on other rows and remove it, all in the same dataset.

Here is an example:

| IP_Src_X | IP_Dst_X | Port_Src_X | Port_Dst_X | IP_Src_Y | IP_Dst_Y | Port_Src_Y | Port_Dst_Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10.00.000.00 | 90.00.000.00 | 1000 | 3000 | 90.00.000.00 | 10.00.000.00 | 3000 | 1000 |
| 60.50.500.00 | 30.000.300.00 | 8000 | 2000 | 30.000.300.00 | 60.50.500.00 | 2000 | 8000 |
| 66.00.000.00 | 10.00.000.00 | 5000 | 7000 | 10.00.000.00 | 66.00.000.00 | 7000 | 5000 |
| 90.00.000.00 | 10.00.000.00 | 3000 | 1000 | 10.00.000.00 | 90.00.000.00 | 1000 | 3000 |
| 10.00.000.00 | 66.00.000.00 | 7000 | 5000 | 66.00.000.00 | 10.00.000.00 | 5000 | 7000 |

We can proceed in two ways which both them of are correct.

The first comparison

```
IP_Src_X = IP_Src_Y & IP_Dst_X = IP_Dst_Y & Port_Src_X = Port_Src_Y & Port_Dst_X = Port_Dst_Y
```

Or

```
IP_Src_X = IP_Dst_X & IP_Dst_X = IP_Src_X & Port_Src_X = Port_Dst_X & Port_Dst_X = Port_Src_X
```

On the left of the comparison the attributes of row 1 and on the right of the other rows

Here is the desired outcome for the example above

| IP_Src_X | IP_Dst_X | Port_Src_X | Port_Dst_X | IP_Src_Y | IP_Dst_Y | Port_Src_Y | Port_Dst_Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10.00.000.00 | 90.00.000.00 | 1000 | 3000 | 90.00.000.00 | 10.00.000.00 | 3000 | 1000 |
| 60.50.500.00 | 30.000.300.00 | 8000 | 2000 | 30.000.300.00 | 60.50.500.00 | 2000 | 8000 |
| 66.00.000.00 | 10.00.000.00 | 5000 | 7000 | 10.00.000.00 | 66.00.000.00 | 7000 | 5000 |

The row 1 was matching with the row 4, so the row 4 was removed. Same for the row 3 and 5 with the removing of row 5.

The two other that didn't find any match, we didn't apply anything to them.

Another important factor, It would be great to avoid loops since the dataset contains 4 million rows or more.

Thanks for the support :)

Answer (score 0):

With the dataframe you provided:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "IP_Src_X": [
            "100000000",
            "605050000",
            "660000000",
            "900000000",
            "100000000",
        ],
        "IP_Dst_X": [
            "900000000",
            "3000030000",
            "100000000",
            "100000000",
            "660000000",
        ],
        "Port_Src_X": [1000, 8000, 5000, 3000, 7000],
        "Port_Dst_X": [3000, 2000, 7000, 1000, 5000],
        "IP_Src_Y": [
            "900000000",
            "3000030000",
            "100000000",
            "100000000",
            "660000000",
        ],
        "IP_Dst_Y": [
            "100000000",
            "605050000",
            "660000000",
            "900000000",
            "100000000",
        ],
        "Port_Src_Y": [3000, 2000, 7000, 1000, 5000],
        "Port_Dst_Y": [1000, 8000, 5000, 3000, 7000],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it with Pandas concat:

```py
# Stack X values onto Y values and remove duplicates
new_df = pd.concat(
    [
        df[[f"IP_Src_{x}", f"IP_Dst_{x}", f"Port_Src_{x}", f"Port_Dst_{x}"]].rename(
            columns={
                f"IP_Src_{x}": "IP_Src",
                f"IP_Dst_{x}": "IP_Dst",
                f"Port_Src_{x}": "Port_Src",
                f"Port_Dst_{x}": "Port_Dst",
            }
        )
        for x in ["X", "Y"]
    ]
)
new_df = df.drop_duplicates(keep="first")


# Stack first half of new_df onto switched second half
first_half = df.iloc[: int(df.shape[0] / 2), :]
first_half.columns = [i for i in range(first_half.shape[1])]
second_half = df.iloc[int(df.shape[0] / 2) :, :].reindex(
    ["IP_Dst", "IP_Src", "Port_Dst", "Port_Src"], axis=1
)
second_half.columns = [i for i in range(second_half.shape[1])]

# Filter df with remaining non duplicated rows
rows_to_keep = pd.concat([first_half, second_half]).drop_duplicates(keep="first").index
df = df[df.index.isin(rows_to_keep)]
```

Then:

```py
print(df)
# Output

    IP_Src_X    IP_Dst_X  Port_Src_X  Port_Dst_X    IP_Src_Y   IP_Dst_Y  \
0  100000000   900000000        1000        3000   900000000  100000000   
1  605050000  3000030000        8000        2000  3000030000  605050000   
2  660000000   100000000        5000        7000   100000000  660000000   

   Port_Src_Y  Port_Dst_Y  
0        3000        1000  
1        2000        8000  
2        7000        5000
```

Comment: First of all, I gladly appreciate your taking time for sharing this solution.

In the first line of code, there is new_df = pd.concat(.....)

And then "new_df = df.drop_duplicates(keep="first")"

Maybe I didn't grasp the logic behind, why assign New_df to a concatenate version of Df and then assign again New_df to the original Df?

Comment: I took the time to understand the script, it seems like it split the dataset in 2 and compare between them. For my dataset, there is many occurences where the two rows that match the equivalence above are in one of the datasets, so unfortunatly it didn't cover this exception.

Comment: Hi, sorry to hear that, but I worked with the dataframe you provided. You should consider a more representative example of your real use case. Cheers.